# Gradle/Groovy Read a directory of files as a string

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a directory full of files, how can i read all the files in a directory as a string.

```
    String contents = new File( "src/main/java/${projDir}/pages/About.java" ).getText( 'UTF-8' )
```

this works to read one file. but i want to read all the files in the directory.

How would i do that?

Comment: Into a single string? It's probably better to define a task which takes all the files as inputs, and writes them to a single output file in a new folder under the build directory. Then use this task output as an input to a task that does whatever it is you're doing. Then you can take advantage of up to date tests and caching

Answer (score 0):

Something very simple:

```
file "src/main/java/${projDir}/pages" eachFile{
  String contents = it.getText 'UTF-8'
  println contents
}
```